# Как работает sqrt в java и не только?

Tags: java

Стало интересно как работают некоторые ф-ии. При нажатии ctrl + клик по `Math.sqrt(a)` перебросила в класс `Math`, там ф-ия выглядит так

```
 @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public static double sqrt(double a) {
    return StrictMath.sqrt(a); // default impl. delegates to StrictMath
                               // Note that hardware sqrt instructions
                               // frequently can be directly used by JITs
                               // and should be much faster than doing
                               // Math.sqrt in software.
}
```

Что за аннотация? Не понял коммента.
Но ладно, идём дальше, crtl + `StrictMath.sqrt(a)`

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public static native double sqrt(double a);
```

И всё. Выяснил, что модификатор `native` сигнализирует о том, что метод реализован в платформо-зависимом коде, часто на языке С. Чего тоже не уловил, тип я его просмотреть не могу или что?
Поясните пожалуйста

Comment: типо да, не можешь - на стороннем языке написана реализация

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нативные Java методы в пакете `java.math` реализованы через библиотеку FDLIBM (Freely Distributable LIBM) - по крайней мере если платформа поддерживает спецификацию [IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Если платформа (ОС) не поддерживает IEEE754 (например ARM) - соответственно для него реализация будет другая

Конкретно исходники `sqrt()` для FDLIBM [здесь](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_sqrt.c)

`@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` - означает, что аннотированный метод может быть, встроен в HotSpot JVM. Для смертного девелопера - это ничего не означает, это важно если вы разработчик Hotspot JVM или пишете библиотеки для него.

Answer (score -1):

По методу Ньютона

```
public static double sqrt(double d){
    double t = d; // t - искомый корень, d - исходное число
    while (( t > d / t )){
     //Заменить t средним арифметическим t и d/t.
            t = ( d / t + t ) / 2.0;
    }

    return t;
}
```